# response.getStatusLine():HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, rest, request, http-status-code-404, urlencode

I have passed date field as string into URL and date is encoded through ***URLEncoder.encode(date,"UTF-8")***

generated Url is as below:

```
    http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/issuesrestresource/1.0/message/RetrievessuesForUser/username/16%2FMay%2F13
```

But it does not able to call the rest resource service and giving me Bad request error as below.

```
response.getStatusLine():HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

what could be wrong and giving me bad request error..?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have other resources on that server that actually work?

Comment: @Noob UnChained  if i pass normal string instead of encoded date then it able to call as it's signature is match with rest service URL but it will fall as it is not in date format so.. it looks as issue in argumnet passing.. still sharing you service signature stuff: '@Path("/RetrievessuesForUser/{user}/{dt}")
public Response getIssueByUser(@PathParam("user") String paramUser,@PathParam("dt") String dateString) throws ParseException'

Comment: @Fildor yes, there are all other methods works on server.

Comment: Before encoding - date is looks as "16/May/13"

Comment: Do you have error or exception trace / log from server?

Comment: i pasted same above.. it is as follow:      .... 2013-05-16 00:17:57,816 QuartzWorker-0 INFO ServiceRunner    DailyReportService [atlassian.plugin] RetrievePlanData-rest url is http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/issuesrestresource/1.0/message/RetrieveIssuesForUser/usr/16%2FMay%2F13
2013-05-16 00:17:57,857 QuartzWorker-0 INFO ServiceRunner    DailyReportService [atlassian.plugin] response.getStatusLine():HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments.

I just resolved by formatting the date as - "dd-MMM-yyyy" instead of 'dd/MMM/yyyy'. and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding the url instead of just date:

```
URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8")
```

where url is your url string consisting date as well.